# How to share a laravel project on the local network

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project and its user has a virtual domain how do I publish it in the local network only

This is my configuration in httd.vhosts.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  smarts.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/smarts/public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/smarts/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is in my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1     smarts.local
```

Currently it works on my pc only but does not work on other devices in the network.

Comment: Which editor do you use to develop your code? because some IDEs have  instant servers to share across the local network without messing with lots of codes.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the artisan command,
first run the cmd on your computer,
then go to the folder of your project like this: `cd c:\wamp64\your_project_folder`,

then type this code: `php artisan serve --host=YOUR IP --port=ONE FREE PORT`
you can find your computer port with the running this command in cmd: `ipconfig /all`

your command should be like this:
`php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.106 --port=8080`

and the others can run your project from your computer with writing this code in the addressBar of their own browser : `192.168.1.106:8080`

Answer (score 1):

**Its so much easy to do.**
1.In windows go to cmd and type ipconfig.
2.get you local IPv4 Address (e.g:192.168.1.5).
3.Go to visual studio code and open Terminal
4.Type like this (php artisan serve --host=IPv4 Address)

Hopefully this will help you to share your project inside your same network.

[image: Command Line image]

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using xampp to host your laravel over your network without using

`"php artisan serve --host "` command then this might what you're looking for.

in the xampp control panel we can see this port: 443, you can use this as a port in your virtual hosts

[image]

Add entry to your `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/yoursite_folder/public"
    ServerName yoursite.io
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/yoursite_folder/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

edit your computer `hosts` file usually located in: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` add your vhost entry

```
127.0.0.1 yoursite.io
```

for other devices, make sure THEY use your IP address on their `hosts` file not the `127.0.0.1` ex. IP: `192.168.300.5` they need this to access your project with your `ServerName`.

```
192.168.300.5 yoursite.io
```

Restart apache server and open your browser, visit: `http://yoursite.io:443`
you can host as many projects as you want just put a unique `ServerName` on it so you won't have any conflicts. Just repeat the process if you have multiple `virtualHost`

Note: In Mobile devices you also need to edit the `hosts` file to be able to access your projects by domain like `yoursite.io:443` or else, they can only access your project using your ip address: `http://192.168.300.5:443`

Answer (score 0):

If you want others to access smarts.local.

- make sure your system ip address is static.
- then every one who wants to access smarts.local should add the following to their hosts file
- 127.0.0.1 smarts.local (Replace 127.0.0.1 with ur public static ip)
- or you should use DNS server in your network.

You can also write a startup command which will execute php artisan serve.(But you have to make sure ur public ip is static)

Answer (score 0):

This is For Laravel 10 & above;

if you want to serve you application on any other machine with tailwind ;
& you are having problem like not able to get css files;
then this is for you :)

step (1) :- add server to vite.config.js

after adding code to **Vite.config.js** it will look like this

```
server: {
    host: "192.168.1.15", // Your local ip address
},
plugins: [
    laravel({
        input: ["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js"],
        refresh: true,
    }),
],
```

step (2) :-  serve you app

```
php artisan serve --host YOUR_LOCAL_IP --port 8000
```

that's all,
now you can access your website in local machine with `YOUR_LOCAL_IP:8000`

Happy Coding:)